# VSTS - SSH Not Working

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh

I made a repo with VSTS and cloned it, and set up all the SSH credentials correctly, but it still asks me for my username and password every time. How come?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I had the repository origin as an `https` url. It needs to be SSH.

`git remote remove origin`

`git remote add origin ssh://<your-repo-location>`

Or (shorter)

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://<your-repo-location>
```

(see [`git remote` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html))

Comment: Yep. Thanks. My mac automatically updated to the SSH, but my Ubuntu 16.04 VM did not.